# Defining the end of the Range with last cell with a value instead of the row number

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range, row

I use two data dumps which are saved in OPL_Dump and OPL_DUMP_2 sheets.

The code I am trying to improve, finds the data in one of the dumps and copies and pastes as a new parameter as addition to the same corresponding value it sees for the other dump.

The length of both the data dumps varies. I manually amend the length of the range every time.

I am trying to make my code a bit more robust
I tried defining N and L instead of fixed numbers of last rows.

```vb
Sub Merging_Both_Dumps_for_Product_Type()

Dim out() As String

'Dim out2() As String

L As Long
L = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP_2").Select.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP_2").Select

keyarray = Range("F" & 2 & ":F" & L)

valuearray = Range("J" & 2 & ":J" & L)

N As Long

N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").Select.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ReDim out(N, 0)

For j = 2 To N
    ind = Index(keyarray, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").Cells(j, 2).Value)
    out(j - 2, 0) = valuearray(ind, 1)
Next j

'ReDim out2(1, 0)
'out2(1, 0) = "test"

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").Range("AD2:AD3") = out2()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").Range("AC" & 2 & ":AC" & N) = out

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure what is your goal here... Do you want to find the values in sheet OPL_DUMP that are in row 2, and for each column value, look it in OPL_DUMP_2 and retrieve a value?

Comment: @Damian i tried to define L and N as the last row with data in it. (My previous version of the code had the row number hard coded, and the length of the data varies from time to time leaves me in need of changing the hard coded number). I am trying to make it more robust in order to define keyarray as range (F2 and the lastest row with a value in it)

Same with the last line of code where i paste to the Range(AC2 and last row with a value)

Comment: But could you please explain what is the goal of this code? If it's looking for a value from List A  in List B and return another value  from List B if it matches?

Comment: Basically code takes the data in OPL_DUMP_2 Column F as given, looks for the corresponding value in column J in the same sheet then
pastes it to column AC in OPL_DUMP by matching the data in Column B of the same sheet with  OPL_DUMP_2 Column F

Comment: @Damian "But could you please explain what is the goal of this code? If it's looking for a value from List A in List B and return another value from List B if it matches?"

Yes, looks for a value in OPL_DUMP_2 column F
and looks for the same value in OPL_DUMP column B
and for the matching values, pastes corresponding OPL_DUMP_2 column J to OPL_DUMP column AC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, should work fine, fast and always no matter the size of your dumps:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Merging_Both_Dumps_for_Product_Type()
    
    'You need the reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    'under tools-references activated for this code to work.
    Dim output_values As Dictionary
    Set output_values = load_output_values(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP_2").UsedRange.Value)
    
    'Store your output worksheet inside an array
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").UsedRange.Value
    
    'loop through the array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        'check if the value in col B exists in the dictionary
        If output_values.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            arr(i, 29) = output_values(arr(i, 2))
        End If
    Next i
    
    'paste back the array to the worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP").UsedRange.Value = arr
    
    'Note that using worksheet.usedrange.value will store
    'everything in the sheet that has been used, even if its blank
    'meaning if you do ctrl+end in your keyboard, the array will be
    'as big as A1: the cell where ctrl+end sends you.

End Sub
Private Function load_output_values(arr As Variant) As Dictionary
    
    'this function will store in a dictionary each key (col F = index 2)
    'with it's item (col J = index 10)
    'Since we stored the sheet inside an array we can loop through it
    
    Set load_output_values = New Dictionary ' init  the dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        'first check either column B is empty or already exists
        'will take the first ocurrence if col B is duplicated.
        If Not arr(i, 2) = vbNullString _
        And Not load_output_values.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            load_output_values.Add arr(i, 2), arr(i, 10)
        End If
    Next i
    
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for the code, receiving Compile error: User-defined type not defined on Private Function load_output_values(arr As Variant) As Dictionary

Comment: @CemG did you activate the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in tools-references? It says on the code, commented. You need it for this to work.

Comment: I have done that, getting error on this line of the code:

Dim output_values As Dictionary: Set output_values = load_output_values(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPL_DUMP_2").Value)

Run-time error '438': Object doesnt support this porperty or method

Comment: @CemG that was my bad and I already corrected it on my answer. Copy the whole code from my answer again. You were fast catching the code :)

Comment: ha sorry for that! it is working now, much appreciated! now trying to understand how it works :)

Comment: @CemG it's simple once you understand how arrays and dictionaries work. That's the key in this code, and how it works so fast. I used this [link](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-dictionary-arrays-and-other-data-structures/) to understand dictionaries.

Comment: taking a look now, thanks for the help!

Comment: @CemG if this answer helped don't forget to mark it as correct so it can help other users.

Comment: Agreed, marked the answer

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Data Using `Application.Match`

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupData()
    
    ' 1. Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "OPL_DUMP_2"
    Const skCol As String = "F" ' 2. ... lookup the key...
    Const svCol As String = "J" ' 3. ... read the associated value...
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "OPL_DUMP"
    Const dkCol As String = "B" ' 1. Read the key...
    Const dvCol As String = "AC" ' 4. ... write the value.
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 2. Reference the source key (one-column) range ('skrg')
    ' and write the values from the source value (one-column) range ('svrg')
    ' to a 2D one-based (one-column) array ('svData').
    ' We will use 'skrg' because 'Application.Match' is faster on a range.
    ' We will use 'svData' because reading from an array is faster than
    ' from a range.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, skCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    If srCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim skrg As Range: Set skrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, skCol).Resize(srCount)
    ' ... which is the same as:
    'Set skrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, skCol), sws.Cells(slrow, skCol))
    
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = skrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    
    Dim svData() As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData(1, 1) = svrg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        svData = svrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' 3. Reference the destination key (one-column) range ('skrg')
    ' and write its values the to a 2D one-based (one-column) array,
    ' the destination keys array ('dkData').
    ' We will use 'dkData' because reading from an array is faster than
    ' from a range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dkCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    If drCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dkrg As Range: Set dkrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dkCol).Resize(drCount)
    ' ... which is the same as:
    'Set dkrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dfRow, dkCol), dws.Cells(dlrow, dkCol))
    
    Dim dkData() As Variant
    
    If drCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim dkData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dkData(1, 1) = dkrg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        dkData = dkrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' 3. Write the matching values to the destination values array ('dvData'),
    ' a 2D one-based one-column array, with the same number of rows
    ' as the number of rows of the destination keys array.
    
    Dim dvData() As Variant: ReDim dvData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim sr As Variant
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dValue = dkData(dr, 1)
        sr = Application.Match(dValue, skrg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(sr) Then ' is a number (the row index)
            dvData(dr, 1) = svData(sr, 1)
        'Else ' is an error value (no match); do nothing
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' 4. Write the values from the destination values array
    ' to the destination values range ('dvrg').
    
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dkrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    
    dvrg.Value = dvData
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save

    ' 5. Inform.
    MsgBox "Lookup has finished.", vbInformation

End Sub
```